# How to get the bit size of an integer number

Tags: c#, bit

Of course I know a method to do this:

```cs
/// <summary>Gets the number of bits needed to represent the number.</summary>
public static int Size(int bits)
{
    var size = 0;
    while(bits != 0)
    {
        bits >>= 1;
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}
```

So the Size(15) returns 4, and Size(16) returns 5.

But I guess (hope) there is a quicker way. But I couldn't think of (or Google) a nice and smooth (and fast) algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps a question for Codereview.

Comment: You could speed up worst case (large value) significantly by slowing down average case (small value) by splitting the int up into chunks of 4 or 8 bits first. If the most significant chunk is not 0, you can get the size from just that chunk and ignore the other chunks.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious OP want the number of significant bits, as shown by the code..

Comment: Are you looking for the size of the type itself or how many bits you've actually used?

Comment: C, C++ and C# are quite different languages with different solutions.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious The OP wants to know how many bits are required for a specific value, not the size of the int type.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Isn't it evident from the OP's example of "Size(15) returns 4, and Size(16) returns 5"? If it was the size of the type itself there obviously wouldn't be any variation.

Comment: It not `while(bits != 0)
    {
        bits >>= 1;
        size++;
    }` an infinite loop should `bits < 0`?

Comment: The above code will not give the right answer for negative values, I'm aware of that. But is defiantly not an infinite loop.

@BaummitAugen: I'm searching for a c-type bit manipulating algoritm, so they should all be more or less the same.

Comment: @CornielNobel - be aware that different bit fiddling tricks will have different comparative speeds implemented in c than when they're implemented in c#. The fastest one for c won't necessarily be the fastest one for c#.

Comment: @hatchet: I'm aware, that it might differ per language/compiler and/or the characteristics of the set you want to have it calculated for. I already knew how to get an answer, I am interested in 'clever' alternatives. Thanx for your response.

Answer (score 3):

Not the fastest, but, probably the shortest one:

```
public static int Size(int bits) {
  return (int) (Math.Log(bits, 2)) + 1;
}
```

Your code can be shortened by converting `while` into `for`:

```
public static int Size(int bits) {
  int size = 0;

  for (; bits != 0; bits >>= 1)
    size++;

  return size;
}
```

Comment: I was searching for a quick one. Not a shorter on. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't short, but it's quick (averaged over the full range of ints)

```
    internal static readonly byte[] msbPos256 = new byte[] {
        255, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
        5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
        6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
        6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
        7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
        7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
        7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
        7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7};

    public static int SignificantBits(this int value) {
        return HighBitPosition((uint)value) + 1;
    }

    public static int HighBitPosition(this ushort value) {
        byte hiByte = (byte)(value >> 8);
        if (hiByte != 0) return 8 + msbPos256[hiByte];
        return (sbyte)msbPos256[(byte)value];
    }
    public static int HighBitPosition(this uint value) {
        byte hiByte = (byte)(value >> 24);
        if (hiByte != 0) return 24 + msbPos256[hiByte];
        hiByte = (byte)(value >> 16);
        return (hiByte != 0) ? 16 + msbPos256[hiByte] : HighBitPosition((ushort)value);
    }
```

Call the SignificantBits method. Something to note is that 99.6% of all possible int values will have the most significant bit within the top 8 most significant bits (out of the 32). This requires just a right shift operation, two add operations (one of which likely get optimized by the compiler to an increment), a !=0 test, and an array reference. So, for most of the possible values, it's very quick. To cover the second 8 most significant bits takes an additional right shift, and !=0 test, and that covers 99.998% of possible int values. The casts don't cost much.

You could shave off the +1 operation by incrementing the msbPos256 values by one. I was more interested in the HighBitPosition function than the SignficantBits function when I wrote it, which is why I did it the way I did (I added SignificantBits as an afterthought).

IIRC, when I was testing the various tricks, this was faster than the DeBruijn technique that I had originally used for this.

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, I really doubt this is a bottleneck you're looking at. (*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*)

That being said, there are some interesting methods in this standford bit twiddeling article:  [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious)

Including the naive approach you took (unrolling would indeed help):

```
unsigned int v; // 32-bit word to find the log base 2 of
unsigned int r = 0; // r will be lg(v)

while (v >>= 1) // unroll for more speed...
{
  r++;
}
```

Or this one in O(log n):

```
uint32_t v; // find the log base 2 of 32-bit v
int r;      // result goes here

static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 9, 1, 10, 13, 21, 2, 29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30,
  8, 12, 20, 28, 15, 17, 24, 7, 19, 27, 23, 6, 26, 5, 4, 31
};

v |= v >> 1; // first round down to one less than a power of 2 
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;

r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[(uint32_t)(v * 0x07C4ACDDU) >> 27];
```

And some more as well.

However note that what's faster in C/C++, might turn out to be slower in C#. Your code purely makes use of some local variables which is actually not bad, if you want to make sure another method is better, benchmark it first)

Comment: It is not a bottleneck, I was just wondering if it exists. For the algorithm I use it, I only call it once. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the the highest bit set, see [Find first set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set). One possible implementation (does not handle zero input) is:

> ```
> table[0..31] = {0, 9, 1, 10, 13, 21, 2, 29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30,
>                 8, 12, 20, 28, 15, 17, 24, 7, 19, 27, 23, 6, 26, 5, 4, 31}
> function lg_debruijn (x)
>     for each y in {1, 2, 4, 8, 16}: x ← x | (x >> y)
>         return table[(x * 0x07C4ACDD) >> 27]
> ```

If you want to calculate number of 1-bits (sometimes called *population count*), look at [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight). One possibility solution would be:

> ```
> int popcount_4(uint64_t x) {
>     int count;
>     for (count=0; x; count++)
>         x &= x-1;
>     return count;
> }
> ```

Sometimes this functionality has even language support:

> Some C compilers provide intrinsics that provide bit counting facilities. For example, GCC (since version 3.4 in April 2004) includes a builtin function `__builtin_popcount` that will use a processor instruction if available or an efficient library implementation otherwise. LLVM-GCC has included this function since version 1.5 in June, 2005.

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants. They explicitly say that Size(16) should be 5. This function would return 1 (i.e. population count, as you say).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding this as an alternative to the other answers here, although they seem to address your question already.

This method counts the number of leading zeros using bit shifting, and then subtracts that from 32 to find out how much space was left.

```
    static int NecessaryBits(int num)
    {
        const int mask = Int32.MinValue;
        int leadingZeros = 0;
        for(; leadingZeros < 32; leadingZeros++)
        {
            if( (num & mask) != 0)
                break;
            num <<= 1;
        }
        return 32 - leadingZeros;
    }
```

Comment: That not different from my algorithm, is it? ;)

Comment: @CornielNobel its the same basic idea as yours, but you are searching from the right whereas I am searching from the left.  You have to scan the entire sequence to find the last 1, whereas I can quit when I've found the first 1.  While they are both `O(n)`, in practice mine will be a bit faster on average.

Comment: Good point, I missed that. Although I think in practice, you'll search for smaller numbers. So I'll think mine will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

When I originally posted this question, the answer to my solution did not exist yet:

```
public static int Size(int bits)
    => 32 - System.Numerics.BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount(bits);
```

Thanks to Microsoft for adding `System.Numerics.BitOperations`. This exposes some instructions to these kind of thiings.